# React props renders are step late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following which is changing the values, but it's always one step behind. For example, when you click on the "paid: false" for a customer, it changes to true but the app doesn't rerender and you have to update another thing on the app in order to see the change. Is there a simple way to fix this in React? I don't know how to research what I'm looking for so a point in the right direction will help a lot.

```
const [receipt, setReceipt] = useState(receiptData);
  // const [currentReceipt, setCurrentReceipt] = useState({});
  // For some reason I do not know yet, everything is working but this and onSubmitFromApp are one step behind.
  const handlePaid = (index) => {
    for (let receiptPaid in receiptData) {

      if (receiptPaid === index) {
        receiptPaid.paid = !receiptPaid.paid;
        console.log(receiptPaid);
      }
    }
    setReceipt(receiptData);
  }
```

Link to full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/korilla-receipts-starter-forked-01xz0?file=/src/App.js:206-675

Comment: React re-renders components when the state changes. Your `handlePaid` function doesn't update the state. It just mutates an object. That will not lead to a re-render: `const handlePaid = (index) => {
props.receiptsArr[index].paid = !props.receiptsArr[index].paid;
  }` You need to keep your values in the state (or something analogous, like a Redux store), and properly update it, not just mutate objects. Also, the `handlePaid` function in your question seems to be never called, since the `Receipts` component uses a different `handlePaid` function.

Comment: Try this : `setReceipt([... receiptPaid]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is kind of weird and involves mutations. You're better off doing something like this (I removed the form stuff cos that's unrelated):

```
// App.js
export default function App() {
  const [receipts, setReceipts] = useState(receiptData);

  // Map over the current state, not the imported array
  const handlePaid = (id) => {
    setReceipts(
      receipts.map((receipt) =>
        receipt.id === id ? { ...receipt, paid: !receipt.paid } : receipt
      )
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Receipts receiptsArr={receipts} handlePaid={handlePaid} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

```
// Receipts.js
const Receipts = (props) => {
  const receiptMap = props.receiptsArr.map((receipt, index) => {
    return (
      <Receipt
        ...
        handlePaid={() => props.handlePaid(receipt.id)}
      />
    );
  });
  return <div className="container">{receiptMap}</div>;
};
```

---

```
// Receipt.js
const Receipt = (props) => {
    return (
      ...
      <span onClick={props.handlePaid} >Paid: {props.paid ? 'true' :  'false'}</span>
    </div>
    )
}
```

[You can check out the sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/korilla-receipts-starter-forked-d895w?file=/src/Receipt.js:27-557)